# VisualStateManager silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visualstatemanager

Hello I am stuck on getting my VisualState working properly. What I am trying to achieve is setting a border colour on user input so what I do is this

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(textbox, "BorderHighlight", false);
```

The storyboard is defined in a separate VisualStateGroup

```
<VisualState x:Name="BorderHighlight" >
    <Storyboard >
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:05"  
            Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="        
               (Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                   ...
         </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

The problem is that the textbox now does not leave the visualstate so it can't be triggered a second time. So somehow I have to switch it back to normal state. I tried adding a Normal state
          
to the group seems this is not allowed (can only have one Normal state?)
I also tried to set a Normal state the same way I set highlight state after the first one is completed that did not work either.

Please if anyone can point me in the right direction here I'd be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're creating a custom control.  I would have something like this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BorderStates">

        <VisualState x:Name="BorderHighlight">
            <Storyboard> ... </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

        <VisualState x:Name="BorderNormal">
            <Storyboard> ...  </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>

    </VisualStateGroup>
    ...
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And then in response to events in your control implementation, something like

```
protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "BorderHighlight, false);
    ...
}

protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "BorderNormal, false);
    ...
}
```